# How to have auto uv and texture size

Tags: texturing, add-on

I have image texture of 1x1 feet, and i want my uv to be exact same size. I do not want to scale the uv to adjust. any suggestion or help or any addon can do it. Thanks

Comment: This looks more like a request than a question. but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: In what sense (assuming it's not physical) is the texture 1x1 feet? What attributes of your image define it to be that size? Are those attributes readable?

Comment: A texture is an image which has pixels. It has no certain size in feet unless you print it (of course there might exist information like dpi in the image's metadata, but that doesn't really matter for display on screen). The UV layout is normalized, going from 0 to 1. It has no real world size at all. It has the XY coordinates (0, 0) on the bottom left corner of whatever image you open in the _UV Editor_ and (1, 1) at the top right corner.